# How can I responsively place a link over an image that stays in place even though the screens change?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to overlay a link over a div background image, but would like the link to stay in place as I test screen widths by taking the mouse and narrowing the screen. The URL is http://jandswebsitedesigns.com/test/index.html.  As you can see where the "a link here" is where I would like the link to be and stays there.  It seems to me that there has to be a better way than the way I set up the txt-link class.

```
 <style>
   .fixed  {     
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: contain;  
      background-repeat:  no-repeat; }

   .txt-link  {
      font-size:  25px; 
      color:  #ffffff; 
      position: absolute; 
      z-index:  2; 
      top: 55%; 
      left: 45%;  }


  </style>


  <img class="fixed" src="images/RFYL-MainPageBanner.jpg">
     <div class="txt-link">
       <div>a link here</div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Firstly, why it's changed to `contain` after `cover`?

Comment: Secondly, there is no background image.

Comment: Off topic, but I read the title as responsibly.. Gave me a chuckle.

Comment: contain after cover... how did I not see that?  oops. the background image is RFYL-MainPageBanner.  I know I am doing something wrong.  just can't figure it out.  really need an in depth course in css.

Answer (score 1):

add the id `image` to your image add the id `linkContent` the the div that contais the link taht you want that always stay over the image

add this code to your page

```
$(window).resize(function(){

    $image = $("#image");
    $link = $("#linkContent");

    imageTop = $image.offset().top;
    imageLeft = $image.offset().top;
    imageWidth = $image.width();
    imageHeight = $image.height();
    linkWidth = $link.width()/2;
    linkHeight = $link.height()/2;

    $link.offset({top:(imageTop+imageHeight)/2 - linkHeight,left:(imageWidth+imageLeft)/2 - linkWidth});
})
```

just for reference this will be your page:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<title>Welcome to New Life Church in Corpus Christi, TX.</title>

<meta name="description" content="At New Life Church we are reaching for a stronger relationship with God and with others; resulting in together being God's expression of love, 
hope and power in Corpus Christi, Texas!">
<meta name="keywords" content="bible-based teachings, spirit-filled worship, interdenominational church, develop a closer relationship with our Lord, outreach, outreach ministries, missions, water baptisms, sunday morning services, wednesday services, children and kids service, students, college students, experience God, sunday sermons, praise and worship, Christian teachings, life groups, mens, womens, marrieds, young adults, singles, city outreach, fellowship, biblical doctrine. ">

<meta name="Robots" content="index,follow"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

<!-- this is for arrow up-->
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">

<!--fluid grid-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layouts-common.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 640px)" href="css/max-640px.css">



<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=160dpi,">


<style>
.fixed  {     
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: contain;  
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    position:  relative;
    z-index:  1;  }

</style>

</head>

<body <div="" id="main-wrapper">

              <img id="image" class="fixed" src="images/RFYL-MainPageBanner.jpg">
              <div id="linkContent" style="font-size: 25px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: absolute; z-index: 2; top: 510px; left: 734px;">
                     <div>a link here</div>
             </div>






          <div class="scroll-top-wrapper">
       <span class="scroll-top-inner">
        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
      </span>
           </div>

          <div id="footer">  

               <div id="footer-content">

                          <div class="container" style="margin:  0; padding:  35px 0 35px 0;" role="main">

                               <div class="c1" style="padding-bottom:  25px;">

                                    <div style="float:  left;  width:  50%;">
                                              <div id="site-map">
                                                   <p class="footer-hdr">Navigation</p>
                                                   <a href="index.html">Home</a><br>
                                                   <a href="im-new-here.html">I'm New Here</a><br>
                                           <a href="sermons.html">Sermon Archive</a><br>
                                                   <a href="ministries.html">Ministries</a><br>
                                                   <a href="next-steps.html">Next Steps</a><br>
                                                   <a href="learn-more.html">Learn More</a><br>
                                                   <a href="contact.html">Contact</a><br>
                                                   <a href="give.html">Give</a><br>
                                              </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div style="float:  left;  width:  50%;">
                                             <div id="site-map">
                                                   <p class="footer-hdr">About</p>
                                                   <a href="learn-more.html">Core Values</a><br>
                                                   <a href="beliefs.html">Beliefs</a><br>
                                                   <a href="the-team.html">The Team</a><br>
                                                   <a href="missions.html">Missions</a><br>
                                              </div>
                                    </div>

                               </div><!--close c1-->

                               <div class="c2">

                                    <div style="float:  left;  width:  50%;">
                                             <div id="site-map">
                                                    <p class="footer-hdr">Connect</p>
                                                    <a href="kids.html">Kids</a><br>
                                                    <a href="students.html">Students</a><br>
                                                    <a href="adults.html">Adults</a><br>
                                                    <a href="marrieds.html">Marrieds</a><br>
                                            <a href="mens.html">Men's</a><br>
                                                    <a href="womens.html">Women's</a><br>
                                                    <a href="young-adults.html">Young Adults</a><br>
                                              </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div style="float:  left;  width:  50%;">
                                             <div id="site-map" style="color:  #979797; line-height:  150%;">
                                                    <p class="footer-hdr">Contact Info</p>
                                                    <span style="color:  #ffffff;">Address</span><br>5801 McArdle Rd.<br>Corpus Christi, TX<br>78412<br><br>
                                                    <span style="color:  #ffffff;">Church Office</span><br>Phone:  (361) 992-9921<br>Fax:  (361) 992-1355<br><br>
                                                    <span style="color:  #ffffff;">Office Hours</span><br>Monday - Thursday<br>8:00am - 5:00pm 
                                              </div>
                                    </div>

                               </div><!--close c2-->

                         </div><!-- close container-->


             </div><!--end footer content-->

            </div><!--end footer--> 
            <div id="bottom">
                     <div id="bottom-content">

                                 <div class="s-container" role="main">
                                         <div class="b1">
                                                 <div style="padding-bottom:  10px;">
                                                        ©&nbsp;2015 New Life Church.  All Rights Reserved.
                                                 </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="b2">
                                                  <div>
                                                         Site Designed and Maintained By:&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://jandswebsitedesigns.com/" target="_blank">J&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;S Website Designs</a>
                                                  </div>
                                       </div>
                                 </div>
                      </div>
            </div>



           <div id="top-bar">
                 <div id="header">

              <div id="menu-icon" class="menu-right"></div>

                 </div>

    <div id="sidebar" style="z-index: 100; position: fixed; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 275px; margin-right: -275px;"><div data-ssbplugin="sub-wrapper" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto;">
                 <div id="top-sidebar">Most Recent Sermon
                         <iframe style="padding-top:  20px;" width="222" height="125" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/fhtSqq1Pxqk" rel="0" controls="1" showinfo="0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
                 </div>
         <div id="push-sidebar">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="im-new-here.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-in"></i>I'm New Here</a></li>
            <li><a href="sermons.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-desktop"></i>Sermon Archive</a></li>
            <li><a href="ministries.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-users"></i>Ministries</a></li>
            <li><a href="next-steps.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-compass"></i>Next Steps</a></li>
            <li><a href="learn-more.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-info-circle"></i>Learn More</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i>Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="give.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-heart"></i>Give</a></li>
        </ul>
         </div>

                 <div id="social">

                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/summitcorpus" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/summitcorpus" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="https://instagram.com/summitcorpus/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>

                 </div>


    </div></div>


<!-- this is for side bar menu-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/simpleslider/jquery.simplesidebar.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $( '#sidebar' ).simpleSidebar({
        settings: {
            opener: '#menu-icon',
            wrapper: '#main-wrapper'
        },
        sidebar: {
            align: 'right',
            width: 275,
            closingLinks: 'a',
            style: {
                zIndex: 100
            }
        }
    });

$(function(){
 $(window).resize(function(){

        $image = $("#image");
        $link = $("#linkContent");

        imageTop = $image.offset().top;
        imageLeft = $image.offset().top;
        imageWidth = $image.width();
        imageHeight = $image.height();
        linkWidth = $link.width()/2;
        linkHeight = $link.height()/2;

        $link.offset({top:(imageTop+imageHeight)/2 - linkHeight,left:(imageWidth+imageLeft)/2 - linkWidth});
    })

})
</script>

<!-- end of side bar stuff-->

<!-- image map stuff-->
<script src="js/imagemap/ios-orientationchange-fix.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/imagemap/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();


    });
});
</script>

<!--end image map stuff-->



<script>

$(function() {
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $(".header").addClass("active");
        } else {
           $(".header").removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});

</script>


<script>

$(function(){

    $(document).on( 'scroll', function(){

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scroll-top-wrapper').addClass('show');
        } else {
            $('.scroll-top-wrapper').removeClass('show');
        }
    });

    $('.scroll-top-wrapper').on('click', scrollToTop);
});

function scrollToTop() {
    verticalOffset = typeof(verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
    element = $('body');
    offset = element.offset();
    offsetTop = offset.top;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: offsetTop}, 500, 'linear');
}
</script>
```

Comment: not sure what you meant by this Victor <body <div="" id="main-wrapper">  ?  Also do I add the code as a script?

Comment: I believe the javascript is working great but I think there is a problem with

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly, then 
put the img and the text inside a div with poosition = relative, so the link is absolute to this div not to the sceen!

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7tzvadb8/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
      <img class="fixed" src="http://jandswebsitedesigns.com/test/images/RFYL-MainPageBanner.jpg"/>
     <div class="txt-link">
       <div>a link here</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

img.fixed  {
    width: 100%;

}

   .txt-link  {
      font-size:  25px; 
      color:  #ffffff; 
      position: absolute; 
      z-index:  2; 
      top: 55%; 
      left: 45%;  }
```